# About bumblebee 12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, bumblebee

Im using ubuntu 12.10 64bit and installed **BUMBLEBEE** with the way in wiki. When i try to run programs with **OPTIRUN** i get this error.

```
[ 3143.700713] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.

[ 3143.700755] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

How can i fix it and use my Nvidia GT555M as a main graphic card?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

try this link: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting There is such a problem described ("[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) [drm] failed to open device").

It worked for me.

Comment: Ok i will try it and will comment the results. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I did that and now im getting this error.                         [   34.968577] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[   34.96864] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running? Now im tring to fix it by doing what it writes here: http://www.ivegotavirus.com/how-to-fix-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: Couldnt fix it still getting error message [   55.193461] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[   55.193505] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled. :(